# Elasticsearch how to make sure that fuzziness doesn't calculate score

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using multi_match with fuzziness as AUTO. Fuzziness is changing the score, so when i search for "Tourette" it gives me results with word "Roulette" first and then "Tourette"

```
"query" => [
    "bool" => [
        "should" => [
            [
                "multi_match" => [
                    "query" => "Tourette",
                    "fields" => ["synopsis", "details"],
                    "fuzziness" => "AUTO"
                ]
            ]                       
        ]
    ]
]
```

Please let me know what can be done to make result with word "Tourette" appear first.

Thanks.

Comment: In the elastic search docs they say "Fuzzy matching should not be used for scoring purposes—only to widen the net of matching terms in case there are misspellings."  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-scoring.html how can this be done??

Comment: please add your last comment to question